# Can I connect my Linux box and MacBook Pro to LG 49WL95C-W with just one set of mouse and keyboard?

Tags: usb, display, peripherals, multiple-computers

Just today I received my new LG 49WL95C-W and has been trying without any luck to set it up the way I want, which is:

- MacBook Pro is connected through USB-C for display/charging.
- Linux Box is connected through DP.
- Keyboard and mouse are connected to the available ports on the monitor.
- Linux box is connected through (???) for mouse/keyboard control?
- I can control both machines and somehow switch the main source (can be either entirely Linux, or entirely Mac).

I could also do a side-by-side style advertised by LG in addition to my main setup. However, I don't want to install any of their software. I'm not sure I will be able to achieve any of that given the monitor only has 1 upstream USB port, which is USB-C.

P.S. I saw the review of 49" Dell monitor that uses the same panel, and from that review it seems trivial to jump between two different machines. I guess this is not the case here?

Thanks!

Comment: Sounds like a KVM switch is what you need. I’d have to look into them more to see if I could find one that’s compatible for you.

Comment: So this monitor doesn't have KVM? How do they do the dual setup that they advertise if that's the case?

Comment: I misunderstood your question. I don't think you can do what you're wanting without installing their software. In the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?time_continue=2&v=d2svy-fqLUs), the Picture by Picture (2 OS mode), or controlling which one is shown is enabled and fully controlled through their software.

Comment: I didn't find anything about the PBP mode in that video though :( I found another one and yes, looks like it's all in their software which they don't have for Linux. It makes this monitor completely useless for me, will be returning. Thanks!

Comment: Do you have the software installed? Did you watch the video I linked? Unfortunately, I couldn't find the actual manual on the LG website or Google. It looks pretty simple after watching the video.

Comment: I'm confused by their stuff. There are plenty of videos who show people who are running only macOS applications on the monitor with no signs of a Windows OS. LG has done a terrible job releasing documentation and support for this product. It looks nice but I can't find any manual or find many answers to the questions I've had while looking at this monitor.